# Can I get page title from referrer url with javascript

Tags: javascript

Our pages consists of forms. How can I do disable backspace and ask: 'Do you want to go back "Referrer Page Title" ?

I can do disable backspace but i need page title referrer url

```
window.onkeydown = keydown;

function keydown()
{
   if(event.keyCode==8){
    if (!confirm("Do you want to go back page?"))
    return false; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have the `document.referrer` property available to tell you the URL.

The best solution is to send an AJAX request to your server with the referrer, let the server fetch the referrer and get the title, and send back this title to the client.

There, you can ask the confirmation.

Pseudo-code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
    confirm('Do you want to return to ' + xhr.responseText + '?');
};
xhr.open('your_url?referrer=' + document.referrer);
xhr.send();
```

About the "disabling backspace" part, you can use the `onbeforeunload` event. Where you'd catch the event and send the ajax request instead.